# Rebase including reverted commit

Tags: git, rebase, git-rebase, git-revert

I want to merge my feature branch onto the develop branch. However, one of the commits reverted a commit that I now want.

```
* develop - merge revert PR
|\
| * Revert undesired merge
|/
* Merge (undesired)
|\
| * commit A
|/
|
... (lots of commits)
|
| * feature - commit B
| * commit A'
|/
*
```

`git rebase -i develop` does not show commit A'. I've tried various options (-p, --keep-empty, -f) without success.

How can I end up with

```
  * feature - commit B
  * commit A'
 /
* develop - merge revert PR
```

without individually cherry-picking? (There are more than just two commits - this example is simplified.)

(Note: The most recent commits are at the top in the diagrams. Also note that A and A' have the same contents; that is, they apply the same changes.)

Comment: First diagram is unclear.  How is `feature` related to `develop`.  As you've drawn it I would think they're independent trees that just happen to be in the same database, but from what you've said I doubt that.  In any case it doesn't look like `A'` is anywhere in the history of `develop`, so why *would* there be an option to make it show up in a rebase of `develop`?

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger I revised the diagram to show the relation.

Comment: I would recommend never reverting merges. Just reset instead.

Comment: @evolutionxbox That's tough to do when the merge was done through GitHub (pull request button) and the branch is shared/long-lived.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to help `rebase` figure out its to-do list from a point in time where "commit A" hasn't been merged yet.

Instead of `git rebase -i develop`, try:

```
git rebase -i undesired~ --onto develop
```

...where `undesired` is either a branch at or the SHA of the reverted merge commit.

Another option would be:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~2 --onto develop
```

...meaning "rebase the last two commits onto `develop`".